# Powershell - Replace function writting output

Tags: powershell, replace, output

I was in a case where **I deleted all the debugs in my code but still got outputs in my terminal** when executing my script.
All of this is simply after trying to implement a **replace** on a string.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to set the value of the variable to the desired value in which you are making replacements. The .replace method is only returning a value to the host and will not set the variable which is why your second command is appropriate.

In other situations, you suppress output by piping it to the Out-Null cmdlet like so:

`$url.replace('>', ' ') | Out-Null`

Comment: Yes, this works too ! The thing is that I didn't knew there will be an output, so I was very confused after seeing some in my terminal.

But if you already know about ther output and only want to hide it, your solution is the best !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to replaces some chars with spaces in a list of URLs. Here was the code :

```
$url.replace('>', ' ')
```

Doing it this way, **I got a lot of outputs in my terminal**, showing each replaced URLs without me asking for any outputs !

But as you can see here, there is a miss... I'm not assigning the return of this replace. The line should have been :

```
$url = $url.replace('>', ' ')
```

And it looks that after assigning it, all the outputs have disappeared.

I don't understand the fundamentals of this behaviour but according to the documentation, this looks actually normal.

As simple as it is, I hope this will save some search time.